# How Xcode simulator is fetching data from internet when the internet connection is OFF?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios-simulator

I have created a simple SwiftUI app, which should display a list of songs fetched from iTunes url link:

```
import SwiftUI
struct Response: Codable {
var results: [Result]
}
struct Result: Codable {
var trackId: Int
var trackName: String
var collectionName: String
}
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var results = [Result]()
var body: some View {
    List(results, id: \.trackId) { item in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(item.trackName)
                .font(.headline)
            Text(item.collectionName)
        }
    }
.onAppear(perform: loadData)
}

   func loadData() {
guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song") else {
    print("Invalid URL")
    return
}
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
  if let data = data {
        if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.results = decodedResponse.results
            }
        
            return
        }
    }
    print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
}.resume()
}
}
```

When the internet connection on my Mac is On, I am able to fetch the data and load it to the list. I decided to turn it off, then I completely closed/deleted the app from memory then opened it app again and the data was still there. This is very confusing for me, can somebody explain me what is happening, because the code should load the data only when the Wi-Fi is ON, why I am still able to see it when it is OFF?

[Short video of my simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccgmr.jpg)

[My question is, why here is gone?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sn0I.jpg)

Comment: FWIW I tested it on XCode 12.0 beta 2 on a device and I can't reproduce

Comment: hmm, I am testing it on Xcode 11 on both device and simulator and on both of them is loaded. Is that a problem in the Xcode version?

Comment: Just tested on Xcode 11.5 with device, still can't reproduce

Comment: I have uploaded a video, can you check please

Comment: Seems like in the video you did not uninstall the app, so the data is loaded from the previous run

Comment: what do you mean by uninstall? Complete delete it? Because when I delete it from memory the data should be gone, but my question is why is it still appearing. It looks like that the data is stored somewhere and every time when the app is build I can access it. Something like core data which I don't have.

Comment: Yes, by uninstall I mean completely delete the app (long hold on app icon then click on "x"), then on Xcode click run again. From the video you provided, the app is still running, so the data is still in memory.

Comment: Ok, I made this project to try saving this list to core data. My question is how can I make the difference is the data saved in Core Data or is it still in the memory? Because in order to save it, I need to launch it at least once. Then when I close it I want to turn off the Wi-Fi and reopen it, so that the data is loaded from CoreData not from the memory. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Basically you want to check if the data already exists in your store (CoreData), otherwise perform an API call. Checkout these repos for inspiration: https://github.com/Dimillian/ACHNBrowserUI, https://github.com/Dimillian/RedditOS, https://github.com/Dimillian/MovieSwiftUI. Although none of them uses CoreData (they just save to a file on device), it can easily be swapped out to use CoreData.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look. Can you check the second video which I uploaded. Why there it is not save in the memory then?

Comment: Do you have something running inside `onAppear{}` that refreshes the view? Hard to tell without looking at the code.

Comment: No, it is completely basic, no onAppear or anything similar. Here it is: https://github.com/BMonsalvatge/SwiftUI-UserData-To-List

Comment: I see what the problem is now, I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`URLSession.shared` caches data by default if you don't change the configuration. Just edit the request to

```
let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData)
```

Comment: Still the same problem like before. At least on my simulator :((